# Cannot find default local server after formatting the computer

Tags: sql-server-2005

I cannot find the default local server after formatting the PC. I installed Microsoft SQL server 2005 x64, but I cannot find the default local server. I can't find SQL server configuration manager in

> start > programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you install a local instance of SQL?

Comment: Look in your services (Win-R, services.msc). What's listed for SQL Server? What's the state of SQL Server Browser?

Comment: brandon, no, how to install it???
bilinkc, i cant find any sql service in services.msc